# VIM php autocomplete node_modules issue

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm using **shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim** plugin for improve PHP omnicompletion, but when I use it to autocomplete namespaces it retrive also names from node_modules files 
[image]

How can I avoid this behaviour ?

I'm using **VIM 7.4**
and **exuberant-ctags** 5.9 to generate tags file.

Comment: It's actually picking all kinds of junk from completely unrelated files and filetypes. Assuming that completion is derived from a `tags` file, you should instruct `ctags` to ignore your `node_modules/`.

Comment: but then what about autocomplete for js files ?

Comment: Then you would need different `tags` files for different languages.